# Why is this throwing a null reference exception?

Tags: c#

Can somebody tell me why this is throwing a null reference exception  (object ref not set to an instance of an object). My code reads a simple xml file then should pass the text within 2 elements to another method. However the exception is thrown at the first line of the foreach loop:

Please excuse my ignorance, i'm new. :)

```
private void openProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I have to pass 'this' (which is Form1) when creating the Projects (Form2) in order for them to understand / see each other      
    Projects myProjects = new Projects(this); 

    //displays the Form 2 (called Projects)
    myProjects.Show(); 

    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load("O:\\TestDaws\\projects.xml");

    string projList = "/Projects/Project";
    XmlNodeList xprojects = xdoc.SelectNodes(projList);

    foreach (XmlNode xNodeName in xprojects)
    {
        string projectname = xNodeName.SelectNodes("/ProjectName")[0].InnerText.ToString();
        string projecttype = xNodeName.SelectNodes("/ProjectType")[0].InnerText.ToString();
        myProjects.buildProjectList(projectname, projecttype);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and checked that `xprojects` is not null before you enter the `foreach` loop?

Comment: where u getting the null?

Comment: @DarthVader From the OP: `However the exception is thrown at the first line of the foreach loop`

Comment: I would guess that there is no tag with `ProjectName`, which is a list and that is null/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `SelectNodes("/ProjectName")` into `SelectNodes("./ProjectName")`. (Ditto for `/ProjectType` of course)

`/ProjectName` will always select from the root, not from the node you are calling it on. The `./` starts from the curent node.

Comment: @user2008060 - for the explanation, see the second line of my answer

Answer (score 0):

This means that `xprojects` is  **null**.
Could you, please, publish your projects.xml file content.

Regards,
Omar

Comment: Yes, It will throw a NullPointerException